# how to close multiple popup at once using jquery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.Ok').live('click', function () {
         $("#popUp").dialog("close");    
         $('#mydiv').html("");                           
         $.ajax({           
              url: "/HRBankInfo/_Partial",       
              type: "Get",   
              datatype: String,
              success: function (stu) {
                   $('#mydiv').append(stu);              
              }
    });
});
</script>
```

my html codes
This is my Html form...
This is Code to create  UI with Yes no Button for Conformation.

```
<h3>Are you sure you want to delete this Address?</h3>
    <fieldset id="_Create">
    <legend>Confirm Delete</legend>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var item in Model.classes)
    {
         <div class="display-label">Bank Description:</div>

     <span>Bank Name :</span>@Html.DisplayFor(BName => item.BName)
     <p><span>Address   :</span>@Html.DisplayFor(BAdd=>item.BAdd)</p><br />

      }

    <input type="submit" value="Yes" />
    <button class="close">No</button>

}
  </fieldset>
```

Thus is script for loading value to division

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({

                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    $('.popUp').html(result);

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is script for pop up dialog

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         $('form').submit(function () {
 $(".popUp").dialog({
                 resizable: false,
                 modal: true
             }
             );

         });
     });
    </script>

<div class="popUp" title="Message">
</div>
```

Thanks for the help

the above code is working for only one popup.how to close multiple popus at a time
thanks for the help.

Comment: try using class instead of id

Comment: Could you provide HTML code as well?

Comment: I'm not clear how you are getting more than 1 popup if you only have a single popup div on the page?

Comment: i am calling division multiple time from different views.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the id selector `#popUp` to identify your popups, however on an HTML page there should only be one element with a given id - I assume that you have given all of your pop-ups the same id.

Try changing the id to a class instead, and altering your jQuery selector to `.popUp`.

Answer (score 0):

try using class instead of id because an id is unique and it will only close the respective popup.